# log file is not Creating : log4j

Tags: log4j

i am trying to create log fie using log4j. please tell me what is wrong with this file

This is log4j.properties file.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=servicesname.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        logger.info("Application is Started"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log file is not Creating : log4j

I solved this problem by excluding "spring-boot-starter-logging".

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks